# Designing most efficient algorithm for the problem with dynamic programming approach

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Assume that you are in exam and you have 120 minutes but you can't solve the questions because you have a limited time. For example, the points and time to be needed to complete the question is below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8tAl.png)

So we need to design the most efficient algorithm using dynamic programming approach for calculating highest point you will take in available time.

Here is my code below;

```
static int maxPoints(int points[], int time[],int n) {
    
    if(n<=0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return Math.max(points[n-1]+maxPoints(points,time,(n-2)),
                time[n - 1] + maxPoints(points, time, (n - 1)));
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n=10;
    int points[]= {4,9,5,12,14,6,12,20,7,10};
    int time[]= {1,15,2,3,20,120};
    System.out.println();
    
}
```

But i couldn't find the correct algorithm, can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Hello ! Before you get help : what problems do you have with your algorithm ? What did you try to solve them ? If you just need the solution, your problem is a very classical scheduling problem and the solution can be easily found on the internet...

Comment: Hi , i can solve this problem with bruteforce method but it asks the most efficient algorithm.

Comment: See answer by Abhinav - the link provide severl solution by decreasing complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, each question has a weight (the amount of time it needs) and a value (the points it awards). There is a constraint on the total time (or weight) and you need to maximise the points (or value).

This becomes analogous to the [0-1 Knapsack Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/), which can easily be solved using dynamic programming.